# Get a list of inserted ids as a result set from a stored procedure T-SQL

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, stored-procedures, output

I have generated a stored procedure that inserts values to the ITEM table from JSON string.
Just like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INSERT_JSON
        @J NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT ITEM ON;
    INSERT INTO ITEM (ITEM_ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION)
    SELECT (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ITEM') + 1), *
    FROM OPENJSON(@J, '$')
    WITH(
            Title NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Title', 
            Description NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Description'
        )
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT ITEM OFF;
END
```

Also, what I want now is to return a list of inserted IDs as a result set from this stored procedure. I've tried to combinate it with an OUTPUT clause in different ways but it never worked. Any idea how to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE [ITEM]
(
    [ITEM_ID]   INT   IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TITLE] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__ITEM PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ITEM_ID] ASC)
)
```

```
JSON STRING: N'[{"Title" : "Introduction to Computers","Description" : "Computer literacy. Basic Computer Concepts."}]'
```

Comment: Why are you manually inserting into the Identity column? *but it never worked* - show us what you tried, `output` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are inserting into the Identity column, you don't need to just don't include it in the column list.

You can output the newly inserted `Item_Id` using `output`:

```
insert into ITEM (TITLE, DESCRIPTION)
output inserted.ITEM_ID
select Title, Description
from OpenJson(@j, '$')
with(
        Title nvarchar(max) '$.Title', 
        Description nvarchar(max) '$.Description'
    )
```

See [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03926e5cd71ea1e342b58e23f2632677)

Also note that prefixing procedures with `sp_` [is not recommended](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2499/sql-server-sp-prefix-when-and-when-not-to-use-it/#:%7E:text=The%20%22sp_%22%20prefix%20is%20used,each%20system%20or%20user%20database.), System Procedures are reserved by Microsoft.